# Recovering WP Login Credintials in Code?

Tags: php, login

Is there anyway to recover login credentials to Wordpress admin through the code somewhere?

I just tried wp-config. I'm asking because my email is not primary on the account so using 'Forgot Password' wouldn't help much as I need to get in now?

(I have FTP / Host access.)

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that via the database but you should
**be carful and backup the database befoure any changes are done**

first here is a link to md5 encoder (youll need it): [MD5 Encoder](http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php)

[image: change password in the mysql]

Hope this help...
Sagive

Comment: This answer pretty much says what the above commented link on the Wordpress Codex says. Please accept this answer Cam77.